# Ubuntu server can't use Proxy

Tags: command-line, server, proxy

I am trying to connect to the internet via a Proxy server, but when I do add the lines
`Acquire::protocol::proxy "protocol://user:pass@hostname:port/";`
etc.

It doesn't make any difference. Since I use the Ubuntu 13.10 Server edition, I only have access to a terminal. Can anyone help me??

Comment: Where do you add those lines?

Comment: from root dir: /etc/apt/apt.conf

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am not sure if you are putting `,` in the line in apt.conf, It should be

```
Acquire::protocol::proxy "protocol://user:pass@hostname:port/";
```

You could try adding these into your `~/.bashrc`

```
export protocol_proxy='protocol://user:pass@hostname:port/'
```

for different protocols. and then `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: That sadly didn't work, is it worth mentioning I am running the server on a VMware server